# Strange Results with Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have a 'users' MySQL table. Users' names are stored in a separate 'names' table.

The index file looks like:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do

  indexes names.text, :as => :name

end
```

The search works fine most the times, but some entries are just not in the results. Mr. "Thomas J Jefferson", for example, isn't returned when searching for "Thomas", or "J", or "Jefferson", or "Thomas J Jefferson". All his fellow presidents have a better treatment from the engine.

I just have no idea about what could be wrong.

Rails: 3.2.18, ruby: 1.9.3, ThinkingSphinx: 3.1.1

Comment: Are you sure you've got your versions right? TS v1.4 is for Rails 2.3, and your index definition style was only introduced in TS v3… that said, are you re-indexing the data once you've added these new names to users?

Comment: TS version was wrong, edited. Yes, I re-indexed the data.

Comment: From the information provided, it all looks correct. Is the name connected to a user? Are you running `User.search 'Thomas J Jefferson'`, or something more complex than that?

Comment: The call to the search method is: `User.search('Thomas J Jefferson',
                                      match_mode: :extended,
                                      per_page: 1000,
                                      retry_stale: true,
                                      populate: true)`

Comment: And the Name in question is attached to a user? (Unrelated, but `:match_mode` is not required - TS v3 uses the SphinxQL protocol, which *only* uses the extended matching style - thus, you'll still get the matching you want, and the setting is ignored).

Comment: yes, but sorry, I forgot to mention it is a has_many association, a user can have more than one name (in different languages, I know: it's weird), but that doesn't seem to be related to the problem: some users are found, some others are not, independently on how many names they have.

Comment: How many names are attached to some users? I wonder if this is the issue: http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html#mysql_large_fields

Comment: definitely less than 1024 characters in total

Comment: Hmm, okay. My next step would be to look at the generated sql_query SQL statement for your User model in `config/development.sphinx.conf``, run that query manually with the WHERE clause adjusted so it just covers the specific user you're expecting to get back, and confirm if the data it has is what you want.

Comment: I added "AND names.text LIKE '%Jefferson%'", and "AND names.text LIKE '%Thomas%'", and in both cases the user was in the results. ('Thomas Jefferson' was also working.) I'm assuming that Sphinx is using this kind of string matching...

Comment: But what does the generated `name` column contain if instead of the LIKE clauses, you have `users.id = USER_ID_EXPECTED`?

Comment: ok, as I mentioned, each user can have many names. Using `users.id = USER_ID_EXPECTED` gives me a different name from what my search term would be. I guess that's the problem. How should I change my index to include all names in the search matching?

Comment: Is the association a `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many`? If either is the case, I'd expect it to include all names attached to a user.

Answer (score -1):

You are searching the full text which will start with Thomas.

So to search the given result you have to write below code in 
thinking_sphinx.yml file

min_infix_len: 1
enable_star: 2

In search query write:
User.search("@name '*#{params[:name]}*'") you will get your result.

Comment: the enable_star option is about wildcards, which are not the focus of the question. min_infix_len is about substrings and, as the question specifies, even a perfectly matching string doesn't produce any result.